# how to convert unicode \u003c to correct web content and display correct content in android webview so what i should do for that

Tags: android, unicode

i received following json file from server . it is in unicode character , i want convert into correct web content, and then want display correct content in web view please anyone help me for that!

```
content":"\u003Cstrong\u003EHas there ever been a more open looking Epsom
Derby?\u003C\/strong\u003E\r\n\u003Cp\u003EThe fact that two 
 fillies - both
unlikely to run for obvious reasons - are highly prominent in the
betting market tells it's own story.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp\u003ESo
far   at least this
has not exactly been a vintage year for the classic colts division.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp\u003EAir
Force Blue never kicked
into gear 
 at all in the 2,000 Guineas while the Derby market has been in constant 
  turmoil.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\u003Cp\u003EUS Army Ranger going 
 to the top of the betting for winning a glorified slow bicycle
 race on horrible ground at The Curragh was only the start of the fun."
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
String result = removeUTFCharacters(unicodeString).toString();

public static StringBuffer removeUTFCharacters(String data){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(data.length());
    while (m.find()) {
        String ch = String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16));
        m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(ch));
    }
    m.appendTail(buf);
    return buf;
}
```

result will be:

```
<strong>Has there ever been a more open looking Epsom
Derby?<\/strong>\r\n<p>The fact that two 
 fillies - both
unlikely to run for obvious reasons - are highly prominent in the
betting market tells it's own story.<\/p>\r\n<p>So
far   at least this
has not exactly been a vintage year for the classic colts division.<\/p>\r\n<p>Air
Force Blue never kicked
into gear 
 at all in the 2,000 Guineas while the Derby market has been in constant 
  turmoil.<\/p>\r\n<p>US Army Ranger going 
 to the top of the betting for winning a glorified slow bicycle
 race on horrible ground at The Curragh was only the start of the fun.
```